# how to call external php file in WordPress using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, jquery

I have a little problem with calling a file in a WordPress plugin using ajax.I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setVal()
{
    var val = jQuery('#custom_text_message').val()
    alert('Setting the value to "' + val + '"')
    jQuery.post('session.php', {value: val})
    alert('Finished setting the value')
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#custom_text_message').blur(function() {setVal()});
//setTimeout('setVal()', 3000);
});
</script>
```

But when this function gets called, it shows an error in the console file not found. I want to know if this is the correct way to use ajax in WordPress. If not, how can I call a file which is in the root folder of site name session.php? I'm pretty new to WordPress.

Comment: You can provide the full URL in your `jQuery.post()` or use `/session.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve my problem on my own.First i have define ajaxurl in my themes *`function.php`* like below:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_head','pluginname_ajaxurl');
function pluginname_ajaxurl() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
</script>
<? }
?>
```

And I put the below script on the top of my plugin file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setVal()
{
    var val = jQuery('#custom_text_message').val()
    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        value: val,
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
       alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#custom_text_message').blur(function() {setVal()});
    //setTimeout('setVal()', 3000);
});
</script>
```

and here's the field, for which i am trying to do in my plugin.

```
<textarea name="custom_text_message"  id="custom_text_message"></textarea>
```

and then I put my action which i m calling to my script in *`function.php`*.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_session');

function my_action_session() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['cus_msg'] = $_POST['value'];

    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

and then call my session value in to my function.That's all i do and work for me and i hope this will helps someone else.

**Note:**
The `wp_ajax_your_action` action is for admin if you need to use it on the front end the action would be `wp_ajax_nopriv_your_action`.

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress, Ajax requests should be made to `http://your-wordpress-site/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` - which can be obtained using `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )` - and you should use `action` parameter to specify which function to call. You can pass the `admin-ajax` path to your javascript file via [localization](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

Add to your plugin PHP file after you [enqueue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) your script:

```
 wp_localize_script( 'your-script', 'js_obj', array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
```

In your javascript:

```
jQuery.post(js_obj.ajax_url, {value: val, action: 'run-my-ajax'})
```

Function to process the ajax in your plugin PHP file:

```
function call_my_ajax(){
  // do stuff
  exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_run-my-ajax', 'call_my_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_run-my-ajax', 'call_my_ajax');
```

Read more: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Where i have to define this action, For now i have put this action to my theme `function.php`  but when i check this server response is 0.can you suggest what i m doing wrong?

Comment: Totally normal for it to return 0 on success. You might want to just echo values and `exit` at the end of the function.

Comment: Even if i echo and exit my value from function ,nothing happen just return a response 0;

Comment: Did you check the response on the network tab in Firebug(or equivalent) ?

Comment: Check the link in the question, the examples are pretty straightforward. Add all PHP codes to `functions.php`. Call all javascript codes using `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setVal()
{
    jQuery.ajax({url:"<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-content/plugins/plugin_folder_name/session.php",success:function(result){alert(result);}}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress works on absolute paths, use a complete URL instead of the relative URL:

```
jQuery.post('session.php', {value: val})
```

Use something like:

```
jQuery.post('<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-content/plugins/plugin_folder_name/session.php', {value: val})
```